# Is .WithMaxRetry() in .NET SDK handles expected errors according to best practices page

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks

I read in Graph best-practices documentation section about the common errors an application should handle when working with Graph https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/best-practices-concept#handling-expected-errors.

My question is assuming the app is using .WithMaxRetry(3) does it cover all the best practices mentioned in the documentation, e.g. retry on 503, honor retry-after on 429, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET Graph SDK is automatically configured to handle retries based on the Graph guidelines.  You only need to use the .WithMaxRetry if you want to change the defaults.  You can see the detailed requirements for the retry handler here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-design/blob/master/middleware/RetryHandler.md